# Do i need to change my marital status in U.S before filing form i-130?

Tags: usa

I am a Green Card holder in U.S, originally from Nepal. I got married in a court in Australia 7 months ago with my girl friend, who is in Australia as a student, originally from Nepal. 2 months ago i filed form i-130. Was i suppose to change my marital status in U.S before filing for i-130? Our marital status is single in all other documents.

Comment: There's no central registry of marital status in the US.  Where would you submit such a change?

Answer (score 3):

If you legally married anywhere in the world, you are considered married for the purposes of the US (except for things like polygamous marriages). There is nothing special you need to do, and you must answer that you are married from then on on all forms.